# How to export Type from nodejs package

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, serverless

In `~/Documents/my-package/src/my-types.ts` script I defined one `enum` and one `type`:

```
export enum MyEnum {
  Key01 = 'Value01',
  Key02 = 'Value02'
};

export type MyType {
  ID: string;
  name?: string;
}
```

I go ahead and create `~/Documents/my-package/src/index.ts` file where I export both `MyEnum` and `MyType`

```
export * from './src/my-types'
```

Finally I build the package with:

```
npm run-script build
```

It successfully creates a build in the `~/Documents/my-package/build` folder.

Next, I create another node project "~/Documents/my-app". I configure my-app's `~/Documents/my-app/package.json` to have the dependency for `my-package` module.

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@my-package/my-package": "file:../my-package"
  }
}
```

After installing the module with `npm install` I can import the `MyEnum` into `my-app` script with

```
import { MyEnum, MyType } from '@my-package/my-package';
```

The `MyEnum` is imported fine. But the `MyType` is imported as undefined. Is there a way to export the custom Types from the package module `my-package`?

## EDITED LATER:

I was able to import the the custom Type `MyType` into to `my-app` script by using:

```
import { MyType } from '@my-package/my-package/src/my-types';
```

Is there a way to export the `MyType` along with `MyEnum` which is exported from `~/Documents/my-package/src/index.ts` ?

Comment: Not sure what's missing since we don't have the package.json of my-package, but you should check if it has a `types` field: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/publishing.html.

Comment: Shout I set `"types": "./src/my-data.ts"` in package.json ?

Comment: Sorry, I think I got that wrong. You would need `types` when writing declaration files (`.d.ts`) for `.js` sources.

The `tsc` compiler can output `.d.ts` files from your `.ts` files when [declaration](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#declaration) is set on. In `tsconfig.json`, you should set `compilerOptions.declaration` to `true` if you want the `.d.ts` files to be emitted by default.

Comment: Please post it as the answer so we could up-vote it.